# Como definir os tipos das colunas ao fazer um copy para o PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Estou tentando fazer um *copy* para uma tabela que eu tenho no Postgre, porém está dando o seguinte erro:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "data_cadastro"

Queria saber como definir que este campo é do tipo `timestamp`.

Segue o código:

```
COPY tb_reclamacao(ordem, processo, data_cadastro, data_resposta, data_programacao, id_base, id_usuario, id_tipo_reclamacao, id_situacao) 
FROM 'C:\ANEXOS\tb_reclamacao.txt'  
using delimiters ';'
```

Comment: O formato da data no arquivo é diferente do esperado. Mostre algumas linhas do arquivo.

Comment: Você pode incluir uma parte do conteúdo do arquivo `C:\ANEXOS\tb_reclamacao.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

O formato de data não está o mesmo do banco.

Por padrão, o formato é AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Você pode alterar o formato de data da seção com o comando:

SET datestyle TO (formato);

segue lista de formatos abaixo:

- MDY | month-day-year | 12/16/2011
- DMY | day-month-year | 16/12/2011
- YMD | year-month-day | 2011-12-16
- ISO | ISO 8601/SQL standard (default) | 2011-12-16 07:37:16-08
- POSTGRES | verbose style | Fri Dec 16 07:37:16 2012 PST
- SQL | traditional style | 12/16/2011 07:37:16.00 PST
- GERMAN | regional style | 16.12.2011 07:37:16.00 PST

Para utilizar a opção SQL, você deve informar qual a ordem de mês e dia.
Ex:

- SQL, DMY | day/month/year | 17/12/2007 15:37:16.00 CET
- SQL, MDY | month/day/year | 12/17/2007 07:37:16.00 PST

Para inserir os dados com a data em formato Brasileiro, basta rodar o select abaixo antes de realizar o COPY:

//Isso irá alterar o formato da data somente para está sessão.
SET datestyle TO (SQL, MDY);